# Currying in Slick and Scala for filter function with parameters?

Tags: scala, slick, currying

How can define currying parameter (???) can change a filter in below function :

```
def readManRleIspBy(value:String)(???) = {
  val query= tblManRleIsp.filter(??? === value)
  db.run(query.result)
}
```

I need to define (???) on other side. For example
`readManRleIspBy("test")(f=>f.rlePattern)`
or
`readManRleIspBy("test")(f=>f.rleName)`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use slick `Rep` for this purpose. Here in the below code `TableRow` is the name of the class you are persisting in the database using slick.

For example if I am persisting employee then I write employee Table and my `TableRow` becomes `Employee`

```
def readManRleIspBy[A](value: A)(f: Rep[TableRow] => Rep[A]) = {
  val query= tblManRleIsp.filter(row => f(row) === value)
  db.run(query.result)
}
```

Now you can write

```
readManRleIspBy("test")(f => f.rlePattern)
```

and also

```
readManRleIspBy("test")(f => f.rleName)
```

Free advise: Please try using better names

Comment: def readManRleIspBy[A](value: String)(f: Rep[ManRleIspRow] => Rep[A]) = {
    val query= tblManRleIsp.filter(row => f(row) === value)
    db.run(query.result)
  }

Error:(21, 50) value === is not a member of slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile.api.Rep[A]
    val query= tblManRleIsp.filter(row => f(row) === value)

Comment: Error:(21, 35) ambiguous implicit values:
 both value BooleanOptionColumnCanBeQueryCondition in object CanBeQueryCondition of type => slick.lifted.CanBeQueryCondition[slick.lifted.Rep[Option[Boolean]]]
 and value BooleanCanBeQueryCondition in object CanBeQueryCondition of type => slick.lifted.CanBeQueryCondition[Boolean]
 match expected type slick.lifted.CanBeQueryCondition[Nothing]
    val query= tblManRleIsp.filter(row => f(row) === value)

Comment: TableRow in my source is the ManRleIspRow